# How to implement the Strategy design pattern?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, trigonometry, pearson-correlation

I am working on a recommendation system. It would be an Android application in which user will input their preferences and on the bases of those preferences, other matched profiles would be shown to that user. I am getting data from the user and storing it in the Firebase.

These are the numerical values and in order to show the matched profiles to that user, I am using two algorithms for calculating the similarity count between the users: `Cosine similarity` and `Pearson correlation`

I am fetching the name of the algorithm from the application and then performing the algorithm in order to show similar profiles to the user.

```
if (request.query.algo === "cosine") {
  // compute cosine value
} 
else if (request.query.algo === "pearson-correlation") {
  // compute pearson correlation coefficents

}
```

As it would be a real time application so this method is totally wrong, I want to implement Strategy design pattern where the algorithm could be decided on the run time rather than on the compile time.

So now the problem is, In Strategy design pattern, how would I decide when to use which algorithm?

For example, when you buy something with a credit card, the type of credit card doesn't matter. All credit cards have a magnetic strip that has encoded information in it. The strips, and what it contains, represent the 'interface' and the type of card would be the 'implementation'. Each credit card can be replaced by any other and all are fully independent of each other.

Similarly, On what bases I should choose in between Cosine and Pearson on run time with Strategy design pattern?

Comment: Why this method is wrong? This is still chosing strategy in runtime, because it depends on request

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of it, Pearson would perform worse in those cases where two user profiles have very differing set of items (in this case the preferences).

Perhaps that could be your criteria? In cases where the number of matching preferences is above a certain threshold use Pearson and for other cases use cosine.

You could perhaps show your user a CLOSE match list, which uses cosine to show users whos profiles have a lot in common.

Then you could show a second list, which says You might also be interested in, which uses Pearson to show matching profiles who dont have a lot of common preferences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are saying that I should consider the threshold as criteria for implementing the Strategy design pattern. For example, I analysed the result that I got from both of them, then I found that for Pearson, a threshold of 0.2 is giving a perfect result and in cosine, the threshold of 0.9 is giving the perfect result. So how could I implement the SDP on the basis of these threshold values? Could you please describe this point briefly?

Comment: I would need a better look at your classes to be able to help you with that. 
But by the look of things, a factory design pattern might be a better fit that strategy pattern. You just call the factory giving your degree of match between the profile, and the factory can then return the appropriate algorith that needs to be used.

Comment: You could perhaps keep a ProfileComparator interface that has the comparater strategy as input. Then you can extend that into CosineProfileComparator and PearsonProfileComparator. Now when you to return the list of close matches you can instantiate the ProfileComparator with CosineComparator and the list of profiles with different preferences with the PearsonComparator

Comment: I agree with your answer, however, Pearson correlation also gives us related profiles. Both the algorithms are there for finding the similar matches. The main difference between them is that both of them are operating differently like Cosine gives us the angle between the two whereas Pearson defines the correlation between the two.

Comment: agreed, but there are areas where cosine works better than person. My assumption here is, a user sets his preferences, and based on those preferences, you match two profiles. In this case cosines will be better at finding matches between users who have a large number of common preferences.
But, if you also want to check for matches between users who have less number of common preferences, then you should, only in those cases, replace cosine with pearson. If you only want to show users which have a large number of common preferences then you can only go for cosine.

Comment: I also want to understand this a bit :) What do you mean by preferences ? Suppose I have numeric value of each attribute which I am taking from user. Suppose x attribute value of X user is 50, y attribute value of X user is 60 and x attribute value of Y user is 90, y attribute value of Y user is 20 so do you mean cosine will work better here to find closest profiles ?